# Error relating to conversion from list to tensor in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor

There is a variable 'tmp' (3 dimension).

```
tmp = [torch.tensor([1]),torch.tensor([2,3])]
type(tmp) -> <class 'list'>
type(tmp[0]) -> <class 'torch.Tensor'>
type(tmp[0][0]) -> <class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

I want to convert 'tmp' into torch.Tensor type.
But, when I run this code below, an error occurs.

```
torch.Tensor(tmp)
>> ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I fix this?
torch.stack cannot be effective in this case because tensors in 'tmp' are not the same shape.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to transform `tmp` in a tensor without reshaping the tensors inside `tmp`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.stack) - All tensors need to be of the same size in the list.

```py
>>> torch.stack(tmp)
```

Ex:

```py
>>> tmp = [torch.rand(2,2),torch.rand(2,2)]

>>> tmp = torch.stack(tmp)
>>> tmp
tensor([[[0.0212, 0.1864],
         [0.0070, 0.3381]],

        [[0.1607, 0.9568],
         [0.9093, 0.1835]]])
>>> type(tmp)
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

Comment: Thanks for kind answer. But, torch.stack cannot be effective in this case because the sizes of tensors are not the same. Any solution?

Comment: @kintsuba you are right. i was just about to update that

Comment: @kintsuba please update your question with `tmp` sample data so can other could help for same.